# Allow PHP/Apache to shell_execute commands on Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, shell-exec

I'm trying to execute a command through PHP with `shell_exec`. The PHP file is hosted by Apache on my Ubuntu server.

When I run this:

```
echo shell_exec("ps ax | grep nginx");
```

Then I get to see data. But when I run another command, for example:

```
echo shell_exec("cat /usr/local/nginx/config/nginx.config");
```

Then it's not showing anything at all. But when I copy that command and paste it in my terminal, then it executes fine.

My Apache server is running as user `www-data`. So I edited `sudoers` and added this line:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

I know this is a security risk, but I wanted to make sure (for now) that `www-data` is able to execute all commands. But, for some reason I'm still not able to execute all commands with my PHP script.

Anyone any idea what to do?

Comment: I have this same question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740802/how-to-make-a-system-call-remotely/22953339#22953339

Answer (score 0):

have you read http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

There is quite a discussion in comments section. Top comment is:

> If you're trying to run a command such as "gunzip -t" in shell_exec and getting an empty result, you might need to add 2>&1 to the end of the command, eg:
>
> Won't always work:
>   echo shell_exec("gunzip -c -t $path_to_backup_file");
>
> Should work:
>   echo shell_exec("gunzip -c -t $path_to_backup_file 2>&1");
>
> In the above example, a line break at the beginning of the gunzip output seemed to prevent shell_exec printing anything else. Hope this saves someone else an hour or two.

Comment: This seems to do something, but now it outputs: `cat: /usr/local/nginx/config/nginx.config: Permission denied`. Eventhough I should have root access because of the `www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` line in sudoers?

Answer (score 0):

echo shell_exec("sudo cat /usr/local/nginx/config/nginx.config");

Try that.