# Php exec commands won't execute

Tags: php, linux, exec, tmux

I am trying to create a tmux session and run a few other commands in it via php.

When i run the script from web it will not execute the commands, but when i run the script from terminal with "php test.php" it works.

I have tried to run the cmds as sudo and turn off the sudo pass for www-data. But still the commands won't execute.

Script:

```
$array_output = array();
$cmd = "sudo tmux new-session -s Server-17 -d ENTER 2>&1";
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
array_push($array_output, $output);
$cmd = "sudo tmux send -t Server-17 'cd /home/Minecraft/Servers/1/17/' ENTER 2>&1";
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
array_push($array_output, $output);
$cmd = "sudo tmux send -t Server-17 'chmod +x start_script.sh' ENTER 2>&1";
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
array_push($array_output, $output);
$cmd = "sudo tmux send -t Server-17 'sh start_script.sh' ENTER 2>&1";
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
array_push($array_output, $output);
var_dump($array_output);
```

Output:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => null
  1 => string 'failed to connect to server
' (length=28)
  2 => string 'failed to connect to server
' (length=28)
  3 => string 'failed to connect to server
' (length=28)
```

Comment: Does your user have authority to execute? It's most likely the apache user you need to grant access.

Comment: It has acces i have given the www-data user acces to use sudo without a password

Answer (score 1):

Taken from: [How to make a system call remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740802/how-to-make-a-system-call-remotely/22953339#22953339)

The Apache’s user `www-data` need to be granted privileges to execute certain applications using `sudo`.

1. Run the command `sudo visudo`. Actually we want to edit the file in `etc/sudoers`.To do that, by using `sudo visudo` in terminal ,it duplicate(temp) `sudoers` file to edit.
2. At the end of the file, add the following ex:-if we want to use command for restart smokeping and mount command for another action,

`www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/smokeping/restart, /bin/mount`

(This is assuming that you wish to run `restart` and `mount` commands using super user
(root) privileges.)

**However, if you wish to run every application using
super user privileges, then add the following instead of what’s above.You might not want to do that, not for `ALL` commands, very dangerous.**

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

3.**After edit the sudoers file(by `visudo` we edit the temp file of `sudoers` so save and quit temp file(visudo) to write in `sudoers` file.(`wq!`)**

4.That’s it, now use `exec()` in the following manner inside your `xxx.php`script.**keep remember to use `sudo` before the command use in the php script.**

ex:-

```
exec ("sudo /etc/init.d/smokeping restart 2>&1");
```

So in your problem,add the commands that you wish to use in to the `step no (2.)` as I add and change your php script as what you want.

Comment: it has sudo privileges but it still wont execute properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try `shell_exec` and check return.

You can need sudo access too:
[sudo in php exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec)