# Starting a node.js script through PHP disables logs, permission issue apparrently

Tags: php, node.js, winston

I'm having a problem with my script. Currently, a PHP script turns on a node script and outputs the process ID like this:

`<?php
exec("/home/node /home/app/server.js 1>/dev/null & echo $!",$pid);
if($pid) echo $pid;
?>`

The script launches but it does not log anything.

**Node.js script:**

```
const winston = require('winston');
const {combine,timestamp,printf,colorize} = winston.format;

function getLogger(name,filename)
{
    let self = this;
    let o = {
        transports:[
            new winston.transports.Console({
                levels: winston.config.syslog.levels,
                colorize: true,
                label: name,
                format:winston.format.combine(
                    colorize(),
                    timestamp({
                        format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
                    }),
                    printf(info => {
                      return `${info.timestamp} [${info.level}] : ${info.message}`;
                    })
                )
            })
        ]
    };
    filename = filename || "";
    if(filename) o.transports.push(new winston.transports.File({
        filename:"./logs/"+filename,
        format:winston.format.combine(
            timestamp({
                format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
            }),
            printf(info => {
              return JSON.stringify({timestamp:info.timestamp,level: info.level,msg:info.message});
            })
        )
    }));
    winston.loggers.add(name, o);
    return winston.loggers.get(name);
}

var log = getLogger("SERVER","server.log");
log.info("Hello world");
```

At first I thought that output transporting to /dev/null is the problem, however, launching the exact same script through shell it works and logs fine. However, launched from PHP it does not.

What could be the cause of this?

EDIT:

This is how I call the PHP script:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'startnode.php',
    method:"POST",
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

**EDIT 2:**

Could this be because of **www-data** user permissions? When I launch the node.js script from php, `ps aux` command says the node.js script is running from www-data user.

**EDIT 3:**

I changed to www-data user and tried running the script from the shell:

```
www-data@vps1130207:~$ /home/node /home/app/server.js
2018-11-13 19:43:05 [info] : Hello world
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, stat 'logs/server.log'
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at DerivedLogger.transportError (/home/app/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:529:12)
    at File.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at stat (/home/app/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/file.js:342:21)
    at fs.stat (/home/app/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/file.js:371:16)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
```

Comment: How do you execute this script from your `.php` file?

Comment: I've updated the question (unless you asked about the php script iself which is at the top.)

Comment: Can you try removing the `method:"POST"` line from your `$.ajax(...` statement?

Comment: I did, same issue.

Comment: here is the same problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740802/how-to-make-a-system-call-remotely/22953339#22953339
you need to give permission for the php user to allow it to run shell cmd.

Comment: I already have www-data user added to `sudoers` file. The node.js file starts, but apparently it throws a permission error (see EDIT 3)

Comment: `chown -R www-data:www-data logs`?

Comment: @OKsure nope, still not getting any log files.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been fixed.

Apparently I was giving a wrong filename for winston, since the home folder for www-data user was /var/www, it was using that folder to make the logs instead of /home/app.

This fixed my issue:

```
if(filename) 
o.transports.push(new winston.transports.File({
    filename:__dirname+"/../logs/"+filename, //added __dirname here
    format:winston.format.combine(
        timestamp({
            format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
        }),
        printf(info => {
          return JSON.stringify({timestamp:info.timestamp,level: info.level,msg:info.message});
        })
    )
}));
```