# issue in transfer file to remote machine on executing shell script through php

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

i am executing script file through php as

> shell_exec(sh script.sh)

script.sh is the name of the script file. This script is used to transferring file say 'abc' to remote machine. When I execute script file through terminal as

> ./script.sh

it successfully transfer file to remote machine but when execute same script file through php it could not transfer file to remote.Any suggestions are welcome...

Comment: `scirpt.sh != script.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute it in the shell you are using your user credentials.

When running from withih a PHP script script you are using apache user or group credentials.

Make sure apache can run your script

check here [Executing a Bash script from a PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151946/executing-bash-script-from-php-script)