# function shell_exec() php works with shell but not with interface

Tags: php, bash, shell

I am doing a script in php who execute a script bash(.sh).

The script works in shell but not with the interface.

Script:

```
<?php

echo 'test'."\n"."<BR/>";

$old_path = getcwd();
$cmd = chdir('/db/ITSA/BILLING_GENERATOR/');
echo getcwd()."\n"."<BR/>";

$output = shell_exec("./test.sh");
if($output === null){
var_dump($output2);
}else{
echo 'Pas de sortie!'.'<BR/>';
};
echo $output;
echo '<BR/>';
echo exec('whoami');
```

when I run php script.php on the server => output ok

when I run the script in the application have not the output with the shell_exec function.

But all other works fine.

Has someone had ever this issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: it's approximately the same problem but the function works when I launch the script with the bash and not with the interface. The files are at the same place when I launch the script. The output from shell : list all my files and from the interface : string(0) "" .

Comment: and what's the content of your test.sh?

Comment: #!bin/bash sudo -user ssh user@ip ls

Comment: did you mean bin/bash or /bin/bash? is bash present under www root? does the app run this script on client side?

Comment: /bin/bash and the file has good access. I try with only ls in the bash script and it works.  May be this command did not work correctly with sudo -user ssh user@ip ls .

Comment: you might want to know this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151946/executing-bash-script-from-php-script
methinkss the rights are not sufficient, you could at least add 2>&1 to your invocation so we can see the error