# PHP - How to start google chrome with PHP script

Tags: php, bash, google-chrome, shell-exec

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$output = exec('/bin/bash /var/www/html/test.sh');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Here is what i have in test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0
google-chrome
echo "Starting Chrome"
```

When i execute `./test.sh` google-chrome is started and then i see in my terminal the text `Starting Chrome`.

However when i execute the php script i see only the text `Starting Chrome`. Why google-chrome does not start when the `test.sh` is called by apache2 ?

I think there is something regarding permissions.

Is it even possible to achieve such thing somehow ?

Comment: Remember, Apache does not run under your account, it has its own.

Comment: If i switch apache to run with my account is it going to start it ?

Comment: No you need to make sure the Apache account can launch Chrome. The apache account is normally very restrictive, for obvious security reasons

Comment: [Executing a Bash script from a PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151946/executing-a-bash-script-from-a-php-script)

Comment: Is `google-chrome` a function or an executable?

Answer (score 0):

Use this `exec("google-chrome https://www.google.com");`