# How to execute shell script with php in Apache2?

Tags: php, linux, apache, shell, raspberry-pi

I'm a beginner to Apache2.

### What I want to do

・I want to execute a shell script with PHP in apache2 by using raspberry pi 3.

### What I did in order to do above.

1. I installed apache2 and php7 to my Raspberry pi.
2. I put `index.php` which was written that `hello world` in `/var/www/html/` directory. 
   The scripts is below.

   > /var/www/html/index.php
   >   
   > `<?php echo('hello world'); ?>`
3. I made sure that I can see `hello world` from the browser in my local PC connected to my raspberry pi.
4. I changed the PHP script to execute the shell script.
   The scripts is below.

   > /var/www/html/index.php
   >   
   > `<?php exec('sh /var/pi/blink.sh'); ?>`

### error

・Apache2 don't execute the shell script.

### try

1. I made `www-data` user have the authority to execute it without password.

   ・`$ sudo visudo # => /etc/sudoers.tmp`

   ・I added `www-data ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/sh` to the file above.
2. I made sure that I can run ,by changing the authority, `sh /var/pi/blink.sh` file in raspberry pi which I want to run in Apache2 in raspberry pi .
3. I added `sudo` to `index.php` which looks like 
   `<?php exec('sudo sh /var/pi/blink.sh'); ?>`

   However, nothing changed.

### The devices I'm using

・Mac book air (OSX 10.13.6)
 
・Raspberry pi (Model B) with Raspbian (Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch).

Comment: Additionally see: [How can I debug exec() problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12199353)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing a script from a PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17151946/608639), [PHP shell_exec() permission on Linux Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/115054/56041), etc

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked to make sure your script has the proper permissions?  Usually 755 will work for external scripts that PHP is trying to execute.  Also, have you tried shell_exec() instead of exec()?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: Thank you. I can run with `shell_exec()` and apache2  the shell file which is written that `echo 'Hello world'`.
but I can't blink the led connected to my raspberry pi. 
Since I can see the shell script from browser, the problem isn't in PHP but shell script. 
I try to solve it. 
Anyway Thank you.