# Set volume with php and amixer/pulseaudio

Tags: audio, php, raspberry-pi

My problem is, that the following script executes in the terminal fine but on my Apache2-Webserver it doesn't do anything.

```
<?php
exec("/usr/bin/pactl set-sink-volume 0 60%");
?>
```

I can hear the music getting louder, when its executed from the terminal using

```
sudo php /var/www/html/test2.php
```

Other commands with exec work perfectly fine on the webserver. Working example:

```
<?php    
exec("/sbin/shutdown -r now");
?>
```

Setup:

- Apache 2.4
- PHP 7
- Raspberry Pi 3b+
- Raspian
- Speaker connected via Headphone Jack

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Is apache (typically user www-data) part of the sudoers group?

Comment: I also think you shouldn't be invoking command line commands with sudo through a webapp. Why not add www-data to the group that is allowed to execute pactl?

Comment: Okay, how can I add www-data to the execution group?

Comment: You could try google for that: https://www.google.nl/search?q=linux+add+user+to+group&oq=linux+add+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.3481j0j7&client=ms-android-google&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

First check the group. One way is to use `ls -lah /usr/bin/pactl`. It should show amongst other information, the user and group who have permission. It also shows if the user, group and others have permission to execute at all.

To add an existing user account to a group on your system, use the usermodcommand, replacing examplegroup with the name of the group you want to add the user to andexampleusername  with the name of the user you want to add.

`usermod -a -G examplegroup exampleusername`

For example, to add the user www-data to the group music, use the following command:

`usermod -a -G music www-data`

[Source](https://www.howtogeek.com/50787/add-a-user-to-a-group-or-second-group-on-linux/amp/)

**edit**

Another way would be to allow all users to execute `/usr/bin/pactl` by adding execute bit to all.

Comment: I executed the following command in the terminal an it worked: sudo -u pi /usr/bin/pactl set-sink-volume 0 20%
When I execute it on the webserver it doesn't work. In the sudoers file I have added, that it doesn't need a password to execute this specific command.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. In order for apache to execute the same command without using sudo, the apache user (www-data) needs to be added to the group of the executables' group.

Comment: But the sbin folder requires sudo rights too and the shutdown command in this folder works from the website, and I didn't change anything on the permissions

Comment: Are all flags the same those binaries? Are they for example 777 vs 755?

Comment: So I changed the permissions of the /usr/bin/pactl to the exact same as /sbin/shutdown ones, still not working, the flag is now 777.

Comment: In that case I'm a bit out of ideas. Did you restart apache after the changes?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the Apache Webserver. Thank you for your suggestions anyway!

Comment: And the users for user and group are the same too?

Comment: Yeah, both root and root

Comment: Strange... Just one more thing: you did try the command on the commandline without sudo?

Comment: I've tried the following in the terminal (Without sudo and the same script):pi@raspberrypi:/bin $ php /var/www/html/test2.php

Comment: The php is this: <?php
exec("/usr/bin/pactl set-sink-volume 0 100%");
?>

Comment: Unfortunally not

Comment: Giving up for now, sorry mate!

Comment: Since I can't pm you, I'm just going to continue here anyway. You mentioned both binaries are in /sbin, but the pactl bin is in /usr/bin, are you sure they both look the same in terms of permissions etc?

Comment: Maybe this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151946/executing-a-shell-script-from-a-php-script

Comment: I am able to execute the Shell Script, but there is still an error message "Home directory not accessible", when im trying to execute the pactl command, permission are changed, but thanks for the link.

Comment: Just to isolate the issue, have you tried  copying the binary to an apache directory and execute it from that location?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved. I'm writing files into a folder and a script checks this folder for the files and executes than the code to control the audio (I'm controlling it now with amixer instead of pactl).

Thanks for your suggestions anyway!