# sudo "-u" option not work

Tags: linux, sudo, sudoers

I have a program that reads a device from `/dev/i2c-1`. This software is called `pa_access` and here is an example run:

```
ubuntu@arm:~$ sudo ./pa_access

Input [0]: 0
Input [1]: 0
Input [2]: 0
Input [3]: 0
Input [4]: 0
Input [5]: 0
Input [6]: 0
Input [7]: 0
Input [8]: 0
Input [9]: 0
Input [10]: 0
Input [11]: 0
Input [12]: 0
Input [13]: 0
Input [14]: 0
Input [15]: 0
Input [16]: 0
Input [17]: 0
Input [18]: 0
Input [19]: 0
Input [20]: 0
Input [21]: 0
Input [22]: 0
Input [23]: 0
Input [24]: 0
Input [25]: 0
Input [26]: 1
Input [27]: 0
Input [28]: 0
Input [29]: 0
```

As you can see, this software reads a set of hardware inputs, and then, prints out the inputs states. For this reason, the program must be executed using `sudo`.
The problem occurs when a user is specified by the "-u" option, e.g.:

```
ubuntu@arm:~$ sudo -u www-data ./pa_access

Error setting comunication with PA board on /dev/i2c-1.
Input [0]: 0
Input [1]: 224
Input [2]: 252
Input [3]: 182
Input [4]: 169
Input [5]: 138
Input [6]: 0
Input [7]: 0
Input [8]: 79
Input [9]: 146
Input [10]: 0
Input [11]: 0
Input [12]: 188
Input [13]: 187
Input [14]: 246
Input [15]: 182
Input [16]: 33
Input [17]: 146
Input [18]: 0
Input [19]: 0
Input [20]: 0
Input [21]: 0
Input [22]: 0
Input [23]: 0
Input [24]: 0
Input [25]: 160
Input [26]: 246
Input [27]: 182
Input [28]: 0
Input [29]: 0
```

The program displays an error message because it does not have permission to access the device file (is the same error that occurs when running without `sudo`).
The same error appears if try with the logged user:

```
ubuntu@arm:~$ sudo -u ubuntu ./pa_access

Error setting comunication with PA board on /dev/i2c-1.
Input [0]: 0
Input [1]: 224
Input [2]: 252
...
...
Input [26]: 246
Input [27]: 182
Input [28]: 0
Input [29]: 0
```

But passing `root` as parameter for `-u`, **works fine**.
Need to specify the user, since I want to run the program from a PHP script.

What's wrong? Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a command with `sudo` you are effectively changing the user to `root`. You need to be `root` to access the hardware.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo):

> sudo...allows users to run programs with the security privileges of another user (normally the superuser, or root).

**Edit:** You should consider following the [solution for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532304/execute-root-commands-via-php). It suggests building a binary wrapper that can be executed in PHP and run the program with `root` privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the program can only be run as root. **www-data** is very much *not* root, which is sort of the point. What you probably want to read up on is [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid).