# Getting list of updateable linux packages in php

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to get information on the "updateable" packages on Linux (as given in "apt-get upgrade") via PHP.

Basically the information I'm interested in is the output of "apt-get upgrade" - especially the line: "29 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded." that appears even if you don't proceed with the updates.

Therefore I tried to run

```
print_r(exec('apt-get upgrade'));
```

but this has no output in PHP. Is there any way to force exec to "wait" for the output? Or is "apt-get" locked for exec() in general?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Might try: `sudo apt-get --just-print upgrade` instead.  Also, user will need sudo.

Comment: In the command line it worked but executing this from php turns out nothing.

Answer (score 2):

1. Is safe_mode disabled?
2. Use shell_exec() instead of exec()
3. Check permissions for the user running the script (it might be necessary to run `apt-get upgrade` as root / sudo)
4. try this:

`$pkgs = shell_exec('apt-get upgrade'); echo "<pre>$pkgs</pre>";`

Explanation:

`exec()` only returns the last line of the output while `shell_exec()` outputs the whole stream.

Comment: safe_mode is off by default (double checked it right now) and I tried your snippet but it didn't change - blank page

Comment: well I'm pretty sure it's a permissions issue then.. have you tried running the snippet in the php cli as root, because I just did and it worked flawlessly!

Comment: Well I already thought that it might be an permission issue because it's kind of a security problem to enable package installations in simple php scripts.

Any idea how I can fix this permission issue so that I can run the command directly in the php file?

Comment: check out this post and the answer marked as correct.. I think it's by far the best solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532304/execute-root-commands-via-php