# Giving php root access to run linux cli application

Tags: php, linux, nginx

Giving php root access to run linux cli application

My server is of Ubuntu build, with Nginx & PHP5-FPM

I tried to do the following

```
$shell_cmd = "someprogram 'runthispath'";
shell_exec($shell_cmd);
```

When I tried to do so, it just won't work, because my php5-fpm is run as user "nginx" and I guess it does not have power to run someprogram.

My server is only use by me, and its for some developing of app, security is not a big concern as of now. What should I do to enable my php to run application, I read that I could do so with editing sudoer file, but I want to run the app without using "sudo" or if sudo is the only choice, I will just do it , hope to hear some advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it an option to simply change the permissions on whatever files the CLI application is modifying?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532304/execute-root-commands-via-php

Comment: I tried edit my sudoers file with 

nginx    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL and it doesn't seems working still.

Comment: @wavemode, i need to execute quite a few shell cli using my php through web interface php

Comment: @user3504335 Your PHP application isn't going to use `sudo`, so of course adding the user to the sudoers won't work.  Change the permissions on what you're executing.

Answer (score 0):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
    $shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
    // you must escape the path quotes.
    $return1  = $shell->exeCmd("someprogram \"runthispath\"");
    //the return will be a string containing the return of the command
    echo $return1;
```