# How to automate OpenVZ with php

Tags: php, bash, shell, virtualization, openvz

Can anyone help me with automating OpenVZ containers with PHP?
I have tried some methods but couldn't make the shell commands work with PHP.

Following methods that I tried:

1. Function like `shell_exec()`,`exec()` with and without sudo.
2. Create a PHP script to execute `vzlist` and executed with cron jobs as root but no luck.
3. Edited sudoers
4. Tried this:
   [Execute root commands via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532304/execute-root-commands-via-php?answertab=votes#tab-top) but still it do not work when i open file php file that run `php_shell.sh` in browser.

Anyone have any ideas?