# Libreoffice source not found aws linux

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, libreoffice, php-7.2

I am trying to convert a files from doc to pdf on my aws linux server. On my previous machine it worked fine but now i am having issues on my new machine. The only difference is i have upgraded from PHP 7.0 to PHP 7.2. and libre office version

LibreOffice 6.0.1.1 00m0(Build:1)

I have tried giving root permissions to libreoffice and the package that executes the command but no success.

This is the package i am using https://github.com/szonov/libreoffice-converter

I am using it with laravel 5.4. This is the code in the package that performs the action

```
    $replacement = array(
        'bin'        => $this->bin,
        'convert_to' => $convert_to,
        'outdir'     => $outdir,
        'source'     => $this->source
    );
    $cmd = $this->makeCommand($replacement);
    $cmd = "sudo ".$cmd;
    shell_exec($cmd);
    $result = false;
    if (file_exists($outfile)) {
        $this->mkdir(dirname($this->destination));
        $result = rename($outfile, $this->destination);
    }

    // remove temporary sub directory
    rmdir($outdir);
    return $result;
```

I have tried appending *sudo* since when i dd the command and execute is using sudo it worked in command line..

Comment: You are using apache or nginx? Any error logs?

Comment: yes apache. no there are no errors. it fails silently.. The issue i am having is apache user cant create a temp folder

Comment: Check which user apache workers run under and then use `sudo -u www-data mkdir /tmp/abc` and run `sudo -u www-data <your command>` this will help you understand the issues through terminal

Comment: The issue is everything works fine from terminal. I have tried changing my vendor folder to www-data permission. same as my tmp folder. still no luck

Comment: Then enable error reporting in your `php.ini` for the apache

Comment: This is what i get in apache error.log

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166051/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-syed-abdur-rehman-kazmi).

Comment: since you helped me in debugging the code. I would like to award you with the bounty. Please answer what you told me in chat so that i can mark it as correct answer @TarunLalwani

Comment: I have posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to either use something like below

[Execute root commands via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532304/execute-root-commands-via-php)

Or you should enable to login to the `www-data` user

```
sudo usermod -s /bin/bash www-data
```

Then you should login with that user and fix all the issues with permissions so you can run the command

```
sudo su www-data
```

Once you have done this make sure to reset the login using below

```
sudo usermod -s /bin/nologin www-data
```

Once the issue is sorted out in user terminal, you can run the commands without issue in apache as well

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the ownership of your directory where your storing the files, Please try the below command on your aws ubuntu machine.

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data  /var/www/my-project/

Comment: composer update ? why that ? i have tried composer dump-autoload

Comment: What’s the difference between composer dump-autoload, composer update and composer install? Please refer the below link: http://developed.be/2014/08/29/composer-dump-autoload-laravel/

Comment: i am not asking for the difference.  i want to know why you want me to do that ?

Comment: compsoer dump-autoload, Definition: composer dump-autoload won’t download a thing. It just regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project (autoload_classmap.php). Ideal for when you have a new class inside your project.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has only 2 scenarios

1. The user dont have permission.
2. The problem is from the code.

I'm moving on the assumption that Laravel is working well with you except for this part

This means that you have access to the storage files, why don't you save there?

If you can save there, compare the folders and your problem is solved.

If you cannot save there, then the issue is from the code which I doubt as you stated that everything is working well previously.