# Allow PHP to overwrite system file

Tags: php, permissions

I want to overwrite my "/etc/network/interfaces" file with this PHP command

```
exec('sudo echo -e "# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:\nsource-directory /etc/network/interfaces.dauto eth0\n\nauto eth0\niface eth0 inet static\naddress \nnetmask \ngateway \n\n" > /etc/network/interfaces');
```

I can see in my "/var/log/apache2/error.log" the log : sh: 1: cannot create /etc/network/interfaces: Permission denied

How can I allow PHP to overwrite this file?

Comment: For do that you does to edit the permission file with the root user, but it's a real bad idea i think

Comment: if you really wanted to do that, make a bash file that can delete the file you want, chmod it and then execute the file from your php script. (It is better to build a program using c++ for this sort of stuff)

Comment: You can try to do that using the shell_exec function, as described in their documentation: http://php.net/manual/pl/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: Thanks but I need to do it with PHP, security is not really important in this case. If I make this bash file deleting the interfaces file would work but I still can't create a new with my exec command?

Comment: You need to run a bash script, or a series of commands within php with sudo. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution using a binary wrapper (with suid bit).**

You can take help from this [Solution using a binary wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532304/execute-root-commands-via-php/48779948#48779948).